# Dev C++ Console Window Properties

Tags: c++, c, windows, ide, dev-c++

I am using Dev C++ v5.6.1 IDE on Windows7.

I have written a C code which has hundreds of line that are displayed as output on screen.

The buffer size of Console Windows is small and I cannot view the initial printf statements. 
I tried it changing from "properties" option, but it didn't help.

Where Can I find the option to increase the console window buffer size.

Comment: You can write a command if buffer is full -> pause. Press any key to continuous displaying.

Comment: Try this , may be this will help ...int main() { system("mode 128"); ... }

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Windows, a simple way you can do this is by changing the console window size with the batch command:
 `mode con: cols=150 lines=50`. cols adjusts *width*, lines adjusts *height*.
You may choose to call this with system to set the console size.
 This is considered **bad**, more about that [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/).

```
// This is considered bad, you shouldn't use system calls.
system("mode con: cols=150 lines=50");
```

---

A **safer** way to do this, is changing the buffer and size using functions defined in `<windows.h>`. 
 
Here is a small example illustrating this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    SMALL_RECT rect;
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = 150; // Defining our X and
    coord.Y = 50;  // Y size for buffer.

    rect.Top = 0;
    rect.Left = 0;
    rect.Bottom = coord.Y-1; // height for window
    rect.Right = coord.X-1;  // width for window

    HANDLE hwnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // get handle
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hwnd, coord);       // set buffer size
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hwnd, TRUE, &rect);       // set window size

    printf("Resize window");

    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that the function `SetConsoleWindowInfo` fails if the specified window rectangle extends beyond the boundaries of the console screen buffer. More about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125(v=vs.85).aspx).